# Generalize neural network

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am using [this latex package to draw a neural network](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural) (autoencoder). So far, I have the following:

```
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=4]
    \newcommand{\nodetextclear}[2]{}
    \newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{$x_#2$}
    \newcommand{\nodetexty}[2]{$y_#2$}
    \inputlayer[count=4, bias=false, title=Input\\layer, text=\nodetextx]
    \hiddenlayer[count=3, bias=false, title=Hidden\\layer, text=\nodetextclear] \linklayers
    \outputlayer[count=4, title=Output\\layer, text=\nodetextx] \linklayers
\end{neuralnetwork}
```

[image]

I wondering if there is a way to make the diagram generalized. Instead of going to $x_4$, I would like it to go $x_n$ with three dots. Is it possible with this package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

[image: output of code]

As you can see from the code some more work is needed. To not draw a specific node in a layer you can use the `exclude` key. To not draw links to/from that excluded node, you can use `not to`/`not from` in the options to `\linklayers`, but that requires a small patch at the moment, due to a bug in the package.

To position the dots, I make use of the fact that each node is named `Ln-m`, where `n` is the layer number (counting from 0) and `m` is the node number.

Finally, to get the subscript `n` for the last layer, an `\ifnum` is used in the definition of `\nodetextx`, similar to [this example in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/examples/xor.tex).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% \linklayers have \nn@lastnode instead of \lastnode,
% patch it to replace the former with the latter, and similar for thisnode
\xpatchcmd{\linklayers}{\nn@lastnode}{\lastnode}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\linklayers}{\nn@thisnode}{\thisnode}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=4]
    \newcommand{\nodetextclear}[2]{}
    % use \ifnum to get different labels
    \newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{\ifnum #2=4 $x_n$ \else $x_#2$ \fi}
    \newcommand{\nodetexty}[2]{$y_#2$}
    % use exclude to turn off drawing of specific layers
    \inputlayer[count=4, bias=false, exclude={3}, title=Input\\layer, text=\nodetextx]
    \hiddenlayer[count=3, bias=false, title=Hidden\\layer, text=\nodetextclear]
      \linklayers[not from={3}]
    \outputlayer[count=4, exclude={3}, title=Output\\layer, text=\nodetextx] 
      \linklayers[not to={3}]

    % draw dots
    \path (L0-2) -- node{$\vdots$} (L0-4);
    \path (L2-2) -- node{$\vdots$} (L2-4);
\end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One last little thing, is there a way to add a figure caption as well? These are usually created automatically when adding images/tables.

Comment: @guy They're usually not created automatically, but by you adding a `\caption` inside a `figure`/`table` environment. Do exactly the same here: put the `neuralnetwork` in a `figure` environment, and add `\caption{bla bla}`.

Comment: @guy I just realized I'd misunderstood something about the package, so the answer is updated.

Comment: should'nt the output layer contain `y`'s instead? E.g. with `\nodetexty`.