# Neuralnetworks package is not letting me define custom labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following some of the advice given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406167/generalize-neural-network), I tried to define the following neural network

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% \linklayers have \nn@lastnode instead of \lastnode,
% patch it to replace the former with the latter, and similar for thisnode
\xpatchcmd{\linklayers}{\nn@lastnode}{\lastnode}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\linklayers}{\nn@thisnode}{\thisnode}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{neuralnetwork}
        \newcommand{\x}[2]{\ifnum #2=5 $x_n$ \else $x_#2$ \fi}
        \newcommand{\add}[2]{$+$}
        \newcommand{\act}[2]{$g$}
        \newcommand{\y}[2]{$v_#2$}
        \newcommand{\linklabelsW}[4]{\ifnum #2=5 $x_n#4$ \else $w_#2#4$ \fi}
        \inputlayer[count=5, bias=false, exclude={4}, text=\x]
        \hiddenlayer[count=1, bias=false, text=\add] 
            \linklayers[not from={4}, labels=\linklabelsW]
        \hiddenlayer[count=1, bias=false, text=\act] 
            \linklayers
        \outputlayer[count=1, text=\y] 
            \linklayers
    
        \path (L0-3) -- node{$\vdots$} (L0-5);
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{figure}
```

However, this keeps giving me the "Undefined control sequence. \nn" error. Any idea how I can fix this? There is no documentation to the neuralnetworks package so its hard to debug stuff on my own.

Comment: Please complete your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Other packages might impact on the output.

Comment: I just found my issue! Turns out the tkz-euclid package conflicts with the neural networks package and commenting out the former fixed my problem.